# UIView block based animation redraw

Tags: objective-c, uiview, objective-c-blocks, uiviewanimation

I need to set `setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState` in a block. I can't find any documentation or example on how to do it.

I need to convert this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]; //The problem
[UIView setAnimationDuration:kKeyboardAnimationDuration];
[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Into a block as well as set the `setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState` property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using block based `UIView` animation you can pass `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` to the animation's options.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
}completion:^(BOOL done){
   //some completition
}];
```

Comment: Ah! Why didn't I see that :S Thank you for the help!